# MySQL query to get combination data

Tags: sql, laravel

[image]

First of all, sorry my english is not so good.

my expected result is i want to get data which (residence unit id =21300 and residence user id null) AND (residence_user_id=25106 and residence_unit_id=21300) in one query

PLS HELP ME. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Raw query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where residence_unit_id = 21300 AND (residence_user_id = 25106 OR residence_user_id is null);
```

Laravel eloquent query :

```
Model::where('residence_unit_id', 21300)->where(function($query) { 
  $query->where('residence_user_id',25106)>orWhereNull('residence_user_id'); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Query :

```
DB::whereNull('residence_user_id')->orWhereIn('residence_user_id' , [25106])->where('residence_unit_id' , 213100)->get()
```